# Problems with MatchIt in R

Tags: r, glm

When I run `matchit` function in `MatchIt` package using `method = 'nearest'` and `distance = 'glm'`, I got the following error,

`glmnot supported.`

What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

What `MatchIt` version are you using? `distance = 'glm'` seems to be supported for `version 4.1.0` https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MatchIt/MatchIt.pdf

Comment: Yes. I updated R to 4.0.4. And now it works. Thanks.